# django image form does not save image

Tags: python, django, forms, image, render

hey i got a issue with saving image. when i use the admin side it works well, but when i add a employee with frontend form it save evrything exept the image.

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'addForm' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        {% csrf_token %}
       {{form | crispy}}
       <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"  >
</form>
```

---

```
def index(request):
employe = Employe.objects.all()
form = EmployeForm
teamFilter = Employe_Filter(request.GET, queryset=employe)
employe = teamFilter.qs
count = employe.count()

context = {
    'employe': employe,
    'form': form,
    'teamFilter': teamFilter,
    'count': count
}
return render(request, 'managements/index.html', context)
```

---

```
class EmployeForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Employe
    fields = '__all__'
```

---

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

---

```
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
work_number = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
team = models.CharField(choices=TEAMS, max_length=200,  default='Teams')
workplace = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Is your view function working fine? If you are dealing with Files you need to get those data using "request.FILES". Please post your models.py code.
Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: hey, yes the function works fine only the image field doe not save in front end form . but when i do it in admin side it works fine

Comment: I am having doubt w.r.t your view function. You are not passing the request.FILES while creating the form object.  Did you get a chance to go through the link that I have provided. Please post the error if you are getting any while uploading image.

Comment: i have found it, you was right i forget about the request.FILES now its working... thx alot !!!